# Issue using jQuery to animate a div given a radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not able to get animations to work using if/else statements determined by radio inputs and submitted with a button. I am fairly new to jQuery so I am not sure where the issue is originating from. The values pass through but nothing happens when I submit the value. (I hope I explained well enough to understand the issue)

HTML

Hide
        
        
        Show

```
    <input type="radio" id="toggle" name="choices" value="toggle">
    <label for="options">Toggle</label>

    <input type="radio" id="fadeOut" name="choices" value="fadeOut">
    <label for="options">Fade Out</label>

    <input type="radio" id="fadeIn" name="choices" value="fadeIn">
    <label for="options">Fade In</label>

    <input type="radio" id="slideUp" name="choices" value="slideUp">
    <label for="options">Slide Up</label>

    <input type="radio" id="slideDown" name="choices" value="slideDown">
    <label for="options">Slide Down</label>

    <input type="radio" id="slideTog" name="choices" value="slideTog">
    <label for="options">Slide Toggle</label>

    <input type="radio" id="fadeTo" name="choices" value="fadeTo">
    <label for="options">Fade Out</label><br>

    
    <button type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
<div id="content">
    <img src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/01/29/11536011/Dogecoin-NASA.png" alt="">
    <p><b>Will it go to the moon</b></p>
</div>

<script src="lab4.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
    const dudeidk = document.querySelector('#dudeidk');
dudeidk.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const radInp = document.querySelector('input[name="choices"]:checked').value;
    console.log(radInp)
    
});




$(document).ready(function(radInp){
    if (radInp == "hide"){
            $('#content').fadeOut(3000);
        }else if(radInp == "show"){
            $('#content').fadeOut();
        }else if(radInp == "toggle"){
            $('#content').fadeOut();
        }else if(radInp == "fadeOut"){
            $('#content').fadeOut();
        }else if(radInp == "fadeIn"){
            
        }else if(radInp == "slideUp"){
            $('#content').slideUp(3000);
        }else if(radInp == "slideDown"){
            
        }else if(radInp == "slideTog"){
            
        }else if(radInp == "fadeTo"){
            
        }
})
```

Comment: `radinp` is a local variable in the `submit` function. Why are you trying to access it in the `document.ready` function?

Comment: The `document.ready` function runs when the page is first loaded, not after the user submits the form.

Comment: You need to put the animation code in the `submit` listener.

Comment: would you mind giving me an example? @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Put the animation code in the submit event listener. And all this code should be inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const dudeidk = document.querySelector('#dudeidk');
  dudeidk.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const radInp = document.querySelector('input[name="choices"]:checked').value;
    console.log(radInp)
    if (radInp == "hide") {
      $('#content').fadeOut(3000);
    } else if (radInp == "show") {
      $('#content').fadeOut();
    } else if (radInp == "toggle") {
      $('#content').fadeOut();
    } else if (radInp == "fadeOut") {
      $('#content').fadeOut();
    } else if (radInp == "fadeIn") {

    } else if (radInp == "slideUp") {
      $('#content').slideUp(3000);
    } else if (radInp == "slideDown") {

    } else if (radInp == "slideTog") {

    } else if (radInp == "fadeTo") {
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="dudeidk">
<input type="radio" id="toggle" name="choices" value="toggle">
<label for="options">Toggle</label>

<input type="radio" id="fadeOut" name="choices" value="fadeOut">
<label for="options">Fade Out</label>

<input type="radio" id="fadeIn" name="choices" value="fadeIn">
<label for="options">Fade In</label>

<input type="radio" id="slideUp" name="choices" value="slideUp">
<label for="options">Slide Up</label>

<input type="radio" id="slideDown" name="choices" value="slideDown">
<label for="options">Slide Down</label>

<input type="radio" id="slideTog" name="choices" value="slideTog">
<label for="options">Slide Toggle</label>

<input type="radio" id="fadeTo" name="choices" value="fadeTo">
<label for="options">Fade Out</label><br>


<button type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
<div id="content">
  <img src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/01/29/11536011/Dogecoin-NASA.png" alt="">
  <p><b>Will it go to the moon</b></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to prevent form from submitting.

Get the value of the current selected radio input.

Define some var for the name effect and duration.

And then use effect name and duration from your conditions with this code :

```
$('#content')[effect](duration)
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      let choice = $('input[name=choices]:checked', '#form').val();
      let duration = '';
      let effect = 'fadeIn'; // default effect
      
      console.log(choice);
      
      if (choice == "hide"){
        effect = 'fadeOut', duration = 3000;
      } else if(choice == "show" || choice == "toggle" || choice == "fadeOut"){
        effect = 'fadeOut';
      } else if(choice == "fadeIn"){

      } else if(choice == "slideUp"){
        effect = 'slideUp', duration = 3000;
      } else if(choice == "slideDown"){

      } else if(choice == "slideTog"){

      } else if(choice == "fadeTo"){

      }
      
      $('#content')[effect](duration);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle" name="choices" value="toggle">
    <label for="options">Toggle</label>

    <input type="radio" id="fadeOut" name="choices" value="fadeOut">
    <label for="options">Fade Out</label>

    <input type="radio" id="fadeIn" name="choices" value="fadeIn">
    <label for="options">Fade In</label>

    <input type="radio" id="slideUp" name="choices" value="slideUp">
    <label for="options">Slide Up</label>

    <input type="radio" id="slideDown" name="choices" value="slideDown">
    <label for="options">Slide Down</label>

    <input type="radio" id="slideTog" name="choices" value="slideTog">
    <label for="options">Slide Toggle</label>

    <input type="radio" id="fadeTo" name="choices" value="fadeTo">
    <label for="options">Fade Out</label><br>

    
    <button type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
<div id="content">
    <img src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/01/29/11536011/Dogecoin-NASA.png" alt="">
    <p><b>Will it go to the moon</b></p>
</div>
```